# JPA query of ManyToMany where A hat no relation to B

Tags: jpa

let's say I have a bidirectional ManyToMany relation betweet products and customers. Now I neet a list of all customers which has NO relation to a certain product. I can't find out how to make the smartest and best performing JPA query... Resulting SQL query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE c.CUSTOMER_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT cp.CUSTOMER_ID FROM PRODUCT p, CUSTOMER_PRODUCT cp
     WHERE p.PRODUCT_ID = cp.PRODUCT_ID
     AND p.PRODUCT_ID = 1234567)
```

Comment: Have you tried `select c from Customer c where c.customer_id not in (select c.customer_id from Customer c join c.products p where p.product_id = 123567)` ?

Comment: Since you already have your SQL query , why don't you transfer it to [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html) ?

Comment: Tanks to geoand! That's the solution. @Daniel: I thought JPA would take the efford to join the tables myself because it has all the information. I'm new to JPA.

Comment: @AlexDe I added it as answer below. Please accept it if it worked for you in order to help future readers of the question (they wont have to look at the comments but will immediately now what the right answer is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
select c from Customer c where c.customer_id not in (select c.customer_id from Customer c join c.products p where p.product_id = 123567
```